# How can I change ciruit ports in MATLAB by using RF Toolbox?

Tags: matlab

I have already set circuit ports and I wanted change ports. I use RF toolbox.

```
portn = nport(file);
port4 = circuit('port4');
add(port4, 1:4, portn);
add(port4, [1 0], resistor(10)); 
add(port4, [2 0], inductor(3));
setports(port4, [1 0], [2 0], [3 0], [4 0]);
```

I want to change ports for example to [1 2], [2 0], [3 0], [4 0].
I can't use `setports(port4, [1 2], [2 0], [3 0], [4 0]);` again because the terminals for this circuit are already set.
How can I do that? I can clear circuit object and create a new one but can I just change ports?

Comment: Are you using some library? This does not seem to be builtin matlab functionality.

Comment: Circuit object, nport and setports are in RF Toolbox